# Make my own deepEqual

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to make my own `deepEqual` function in JavaScript.  It will compare two values and return true if they are the same values.  If those two values are objects, it will do a recursion, calling `deepEqual` again to compare the values inside those objects.

Is there anyone that can help me?  I think the most confusing part is how to iterate over the properties of the objects and whether those properties have the same name and also same values.

I wrote some of the code as below:

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
    if ((typeof a === "object") && (typeof b === "object")) {
        deepEqual(a, b);
    } else {
        if (a !== b) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: `if (x) { return false; } else { return true; }` → `return !x;`

Answer (score 0):

What your code is currently doing is not really recursion.

Let's say I give it `{}` and `{}` to compare. They should report as equal, right?

Your code goes:

- call `deepEqual({},{});`
- `typeof a === "object"` - true!
- `typeof b === "object"` - true!
- therefore, call `deepEqual(a,b)`

But hang on... that's exactly the same as the first call! You have a nice infinite loop.

Instead, you should use `for..in` loops on the properties of `a` and `b`, and calling `deepEqual` on *those* properties.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now.  But how do I call deepEqual on those object properties? I wouldn't know what is the name of those properties.  Is there a code to iterate through object properties?

sorry, edited, object.keys << this is to go through object properties. thanks!